# I found a short CSS snippet that wont work on jsfiddle

Tags: css

I need 3 dots "typing animation", I found something beautiful online -> https://codepen.io/mattonit/pen/vLoddq

The problem is it wont work, even on jsfiddle it stops working.

Ive tried hacking at the css a bit -> https://jsfiddle.net/leathan/nfhod84k/ but all i get are 3 dots that jump together :(

**CSS in question**

```
div#wave {
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.dot {
        display:inline-block;
        width:12px;
        height:12px;
        border-radius:50%;
        margin-right:3px;
        background:#303131;
        animation: wave 1.3s linear infinite;

    &:nth-child(2) {
        animation-delay: -1.1s;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
        animation-delay: -0.9s;
    }
}


@keyframes wave {
    0%, 60%, 100% {
        transform: initial;
    }

    30% {
        transform: translateY(-15px);
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="wave">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Change "language" in jsfiddle to scss (top right corner)

Comment: I figured it out already, The problem was I was using SCSS and not pure CSS. I converted it to CSS and it worked.

P.S. You guys are wonderful, hopefully this helps others, going to select correct answer at random :D

Comment: You mind posting that as an answer since I cant? Thanks by the way!

Comment: yes you needed to convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Codepen they've turned on a precompiler for Sass, which turns it into normal CSS. You either have to turn the precompiler on in jsfiddle, or use the compiled css directly:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #F6F7F8;
}

div#wave {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50vh;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
div#wave .dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 3px;
  background: #303131;
  animation: wave 1.3s linear infinite;
}
div#wave .dot:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}
div#wave .dot:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

@keyframes wave {
  0%, 60%, 100% {
    transform: initial;
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
```

The giveaway is the nesting ;)

Answer (score 2):

See the codepen code. Its *SASS*. You need to convert the *SCSS* to *CSS*

You can use this [site](https://www.sassmeister.com/) to convert as well.

[image]

***The working version of the dots.***

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #F6F7F8;
}

div#wave {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50vh;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

div#wave .dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 3px;
  background: #303131;
  animation: wave 1.3s linear infinite;
}

div#wave .dot:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

div#wave .dot:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

@keyframes wave {
  0%,
  60%,
  100% {
    transform: initial;
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wave">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's written in LESS. Try swapping out the below.

```css
div#wave {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50vh;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
div#wave .dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 3px;
  background: green;
  animation: wave 1.3s linear infinite;
}
   

div#wave .dot:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
 

}
div#wave .dot:nth-child(3) {
  background:yellow;}

@keyframes wave {
  0%, 60%, 100% {
    transform: initial;
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wave">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are using SCSS code. SCSS needs to be compiled into CSS. USe the below-compiled CSS of the corresponding SCSS.

```
 html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #F6F7F8;
}

div#wave {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50vh;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
div#wave .dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 3px;
  background: #303131;
  animation: wave 1.3s linear infinite;
}
div#wave .dot:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}
div#wave .dot:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

@keyframes wave {
  0%, 60%, 100% {
    transform: initial;
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
div#wave {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50vh;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
div#wave .dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 3px;
  background: #303131;
  animation: wave 1.3s linear infinite;
}
div#wave .dot:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}
div#wave .dot:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

@keyframes wave {
  0%, 60%, 100% {
    transform: initial;
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wave">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```